# .replace(/'/g, '"'); replacement single by double quotes is not working in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, replace

I have a list of strings named "mylist" with the next format

```
[
...
"P10='javier';P15='sophia';Q10='cocinar';Q15='cantar'",
...
]
```

when I make the replacement and run the code with "node script.js" in my terminal, the replacement is not done

```
mylist.forEach(e => {
    e.replace(/'/g, '"');
});

console.log(mylist[5]);
```

This is the output

```
P10='javier';P15='sophia';Q10='cocinar';Q15='cantar'
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I solve this?

Comment: `replace()` doesn't modify the string in place, you need to assign the result somewhere.

Comment: Try using `map` instead to create a new array, ie `let newList = mylist.map(e => e.replace(/'/g, '"'))`

Comment: Thanks @Phil It works!

Comment: Do you know why this was happenig?

Comment: @Osiris the top comment from Barmar explains why. `forEach` doesn't apply the value returned by the callback to anything so your modified strings weren't going anywhere.

Comment: rare, I read that replace() was a destructive function, but anyway thanks both! :)

Comment: Where did you read that? Because it is not true. JavaScript strings are immutable. Also see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Comment: Strings in JavaScript are immutable - there is no way to modify them in place, you can only create a new string with modified content.